# DataTable not sorting correctly with certain combinations of text and numbers

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables

I have a jQuery datatable that is configured as follows:

```
$('#invoiceListing').dataTable({
  "aaSorting": [[0, "desc"]],
  "bPaginate": false,
  "bInfo": false,
  "bFilter": false,
  "bStateSave": false,
  "aoColumns": [
    null, 
    { "sType": "date" },
    null, 
    { "sType": "currency" }, 
    { "sType": "date" }, 
    { "bSortable": false }
  ]
});
```

The third column, defined with no special type, contains the name of the invoice. It has been discovered that when certain combinations of text and numbers are used, it doesn't sort properly.

Take for example, the following two invoices:

```
Month A - Month B - Sorts correctly
Month 1 - Month 2 - doesnt sort at all
Month 1a - Month 2a - Sorts correctly
```

Why would values ending with a number not sort? Adding an additional character to the end immediately causes them to start sorting again.

Edit: DataTables version in use is  * Version:     1.7.6

Comment: I never used aoColumns but what happened when you set "bSortable": true instead of false ?

Comment: Hi John, aoColumns is an array, whereby you can set various properties for each column. That bSortable relates to the end column in the table, which contains the edit/view buttons, and therefore sorting is disabled on that column. It won't affect the sorting on the 3rd column.

Comment: Ok. You need to use this aoColumns ? In all my apps I used columns: [  {data: "number"}, ... ] And this way, I can sort all I want and set various properties for each columns.

Comment: It looks like `columns` was introduced in v1.10.0. Unfortunately i'm using v1.7.6

Comment: Yes :/. And Have you tried `"sType": "string"`  or `"sType": "natural"`?

Comment: @John, that seems to have cured it! I didn't even think to try it, as I assumed string would be the default! Weird!

Answer (score 1):

I add an answer to close this question.

Specify `sType` as string will fix the problem.

```
"sType": "string"
```